# How to divide each element in a 2d numpy array in relation to its index value without the use of nested for loops?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to improve the performance of some code I am translating from MATLAB to Python, and have found that using nested for loops like so:

```
    arr1 = np.zeros((NN, MM))
    for i in range(NN):
        for j in range(MM):
            arr1[i, j] = arr[i, j]/(1+np.abs(i-j))
```

Is causing the script to run for a couple seconds. Since I am going to be using this code on a large dataset this could potentially waste hours of computation time unnecessarily.

Is there any way to use vectorization/broadcasting to achieve the same affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could precalculate the indices like this.

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.zeros((NN, MM))
```

Then use numpy indices function, which returns a 3d matrix where the first index indicates the either i or j

```
grid = np.indices(arr1.shape)
```

Then divide.

```
arr1 /= (1+np.abs(grid[0]-grid[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr1` is `np.zeros`, then the whole operation is redundant, hehe.

But yes, it is possible to speed the operation up - if we focus on the denominator - `(1+np.abs(i-j))`, you can break it up this way:

`J = np.tile(np.arange(MM), (NN, 1))`

`I = np.tile(np.reshape(np.arange(NN), (NN, 1)), (1, MM))`

and then let

`x = x / (1 + I - J)`

Be mindful, however, that `1 + I - J` will equal zero when `I = J + 1`.